# How to create an air distortion/blur effect in eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I would like to recreate an air distortion/blur effect like the ones seen in marvel vs capcom 3 to give more "punch" to my animations (images attached to give an idea of what im looking for)[image]

Comment: still / animation ?

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it would be to play with Principled BSDF Transmission and IOR.

[image: Mesh that looks like a Christmas tree]

I modeled a crude Christmas tree like shape by taking a cylinder and adding some edge loops to it. Next I selected randomly some of the faces and extruded them along individual normals. Then I moved the extruded vertices down.

[image: Material]

and set the Principled BSDF transmission to 1 and IOR to 1.01.

[image: The almost invisible mesh]

This basically means that the material is almost air but not quite. It's quite close to warm air with a lot of distortion.

[image: Screen Space Reflections]

Remember to check Screen Space Reflections under Render Properties and Refraction under Screen Space Reflections.

[image: Screen Space Refraction]

and Screen Space Refraction under Material properties.

Next I animated the object to scale up, follow a curve and vanish by changing IOR from 1.01 to 1.00.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it's possible due to the way EEVEE handles lighting and refraction calculations. I went with my intuition to  try and create a node setup that could be used to warp the background similarly to what you showed (animating it, and making it "pop" in and out of existence is a later step). I tried adding this to a plane in front of the background. However, while I could get a rather convincing replica using Cycles, the same thing gives jack-all-nothing in EEVEE. See the images below:

**Cycles**
[image: CyclesWarp]

**EEVEE** (Nothing but disappointment)
[image: EeveeWarp]

To anyone reading - If I am incorrect, and there is in fact a way to do this, please feel free to share, as this would be a rather substantial answer.

Comment: In post there is always ways to mix Cycles and Eevee, have you tried this node setup doing that?