# Is there a way to achieve/improve an effect of hot air distortion in EEVEE Blender without reflections?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, reflection, distort

I've seen this post:
[How to create an air distortion/blur effect in eevee?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195079/how-to-create-an-air-distortion-blur-effect-in-eevee)

I've created just a plane object and assigned the following material to it. My settings and Node Setup are in some sense similar to the post above, but in my scene I move camera in 3D I have light sources etc At some angles as shown in this example picture I see the reflections from the light source. Is this correctable in any way? I only need the distortion...

[image]

Comment: Have an object with noise material, use compositor to displace by the noise?

Comment: Use refraction bsdf instead of glass

Comment: Thank you! This is a good suggestion. I accepted the answer below, but I think leaving Light specular 
 and using Refraction BSDF should actually be better for most use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn **Specular** to **0** in the light settings panel.[image]

Comment: Haha. As simple as that! Thank you :)